# cannot modify the store in Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, reducers

I allow myself to ask for help because I cannot find where the problem comes from, I just want to insert / modify data in my store and impossible, yet it is not my first ...

**My store**

```js
const initilaState = {
    estimates: [],
    currentEstimate: {
        customer: {},
        products: []
    }

}
```

**add object to proucts array**

```js
        case "ADD_PRODUCT_TO_CURRENT_ESTIMATE":

            return {
                estimates: state.estimates,
                currentEstimate: {
                    customer: {},
                    products: [...state.currentEstimate.products, action.payload]
                }
            }
```

**add object to customer object**

```js
        case "ADD_CUSTOMER_CURRENT_ESTIMATE":
            return {
                ...state,
                currentEstimate: {
                    customer: action.payload

                }
            }
```

[image: reducer-error]

I don't understand why, normally there is no problem with an empty array.

Even if I remove products from my reducers and want to add a customer, the error goes away but the state doesn't change.

Thank in advance for your help :)

**--------estimatesreducer-------------**

```js
const initilaState = {
    estimates: [],
    currentEstimate: {
        customer: {},
        products: []
    }

}

export default function estimatesReducer(state = initilaState, action){
    switch (action.type){
        case "GET_ESTIMATES":
            return {
                estimates: [
                    ...action.payload
                ]
            }

        case "DELETE_ESTIMATE":
            return {
                estimates: state.estimates.filter(estimate => estimate.id !== action.payload)
            }

        case "ADD_PRODUCT_TO_CURRENT_ESTIMATE":

            return {
                ...state,
                estimates: state.estimates,
                currentEstimate: {
                    customer: {},
                    products: [...state.currentEstimate.products, action.payload]
                }
            }

        case "ADD_CUSTOMER_CURRENT_ESTIMATE":
            return {
                ...state,
                currentEstimate: {
                    ...state.currentEstimate,
                    customer: action.payload
                }
            }

/*        case "DELETE_PRODUCT_CURRENT_ESTIMATE" :
            return {
                estimates: state.estimates,
                currentEstimate: {
                    ...state.currentEstimate,
                    products: state.currentEstimate.products.filter(product => product.id !== action.payload)

                }
            }*/

        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to show more about your reducer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This action deletes your `product` from `currentEstimate`

```
case "ADD_CUSTOMER_CURRENT_ESTIMATE":
            return {
                ...state,
                currentEstimate: {
                    customer: action.payload

                }
            }
```

You must not forget to set previous state on reducer

```
case "ADD_CUSTOMER_CURRENT_ESTIMATE":
        return {
            ...state,
            currentEstimate: {
                ...state.currentEstimate
                customer: action.payload
            }
        }
```

You also forgot to return a state in your first action

```
case "ADD_PRODUCT_TO_CURRENT_ESTIMATE":

        return {
            ...state
            estimates: state.estimates,
            currentEstimate: {
                customer: {},
                products: [...state.currentEstimate.products, action.payload]
            }
        }
```

UPD: You have 2 actions which remove currentEstimate from the state - `GET_ESTIMATES` and `DELETE_ESTIMATE`, so when you call `ADD_PRODUCT_TO_CURRENT_ESTIMATE` after, you get the error

Comment: Yes precisely, I want to overwrite the old customer value, there is just one customer not several but despite your corrections, I still have the errors on "Cannot read property 'products' of undefined"

Comment: maybe you have other actions which remove `currentEstimate` from the state?

Comment: so, yeah you have 2 actions which remove `currentEstimate` from the state `GET_ESTIMATES` and `DELETE_ESTIMATE`

Comment: Yes you are right I added the state and it works, thank you very much, sometimes you just have to have an outside look :)

Comment: Was glad to help out!)